# Importing None fields in a CSV

Tags: python, django, csv, try-except

I have an historical db table of people in jobs that includes start and end date fields. I am inserting from a csv, and my script worked fine, except Python/Django sees my None fields as 'None', and it refuses to insert the rows that have empty end dates, meaning, all current jobholders are skipped. This except portion of a try/except failed:

```
    except ValidationError as v:
        if row['end_date'] == 'null' or 'None' or '':
            row['end_date'] = None
```

as did this one:

```
    except ValidationError as v:
        if row['end_date'] in ['null', 'None', '']:
            row['end_date'] = None
```

I solved the problem by filtering out the current jobholders, and running them in a separate csv with the script modified to:

```
            end_date=None
```

However, what I really need is some way to use a variable, like value...

```
        if row[value] == 'None':
            row[value] = None
```

because I have more csv's to run, with other fields besides dates, and some of them are going to have empty/None values, too.

Would some kind of string replace work?

```
        if row[value] == 'None':
            row[value].replace(row[value], None)
```

or maybe default=None in the definition of the end_date field on my model? But then how do I make Django see the default value instead of the empty/None in the csv? According to the docs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default "The default value is used when new model instances are created and a value isn’t provided for the field.". But I'm not sure how that would have worked here. Would I get the default value, or would I get the ValidationError?

Finally, were my efforts to fix this in the except block misguided? What are the limits of what an except block can do to fix, as opposed to warn about, failures in the try block?

Thanks.

EDIT - the code -

```
#! usr/local/bin/python3.7
# coding: utf-8

import csv
import sys
import logging

from os import environ
import django
sys.path.append('/home/malikarumi/Projects/hattie/hattie')

environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'hattie.settings'
django.setup()

from people.models import Company, Associate, CareerHistory
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


# logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('2019-05-13_inserts.txt')
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)


with open('members6') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    fieldnames = [
        'last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'suffix',
        'title', 'start_date', 'end_date'
    ]
    pc = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Associate)
    org = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Company)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            name_string = row['last_name'], row['first_name'], row['middle_name'], row['suffix']
            associate_instance = Associate.objects.create(
                last_name=row['last_name'], first_name=row['first_name'],
                middle_name=row['middle_name'], suffix=row['suffix'],
                slug=slugify(name_string))
            CareerHistory.objects.create(
                content_type_pc=pc, object_id_pc=associate_instance.uniqid,
                content_type_org=org, object_id_org="828f4116-38eb-4f0c-9c5a-96a93682d106",
                title=row['title'], start_date=row['start_date'],
                end_date=row['end_date']
            )
        except IntegrityError as e:
            logger.warning(f"Check for dupes: {name_string}, {e}")
            continue
        except ValidationError as v:
            if row['end_date'] in ['null', 'None', '']:
                row['end_date'] = None


p.s. This also gets a name error:
        value = row[f'{value}']
```

Edit - the csv

```
last_name   first_name  middle_name suffix  slug    title   start_date  end_date
Clarke  John    Hessin          Associate   1916-10-09  1922-09-18
Sutherland  George              Associate   1922-10-02  1938-01-17
Butler  Pierce              Associate   1923-01-02  1939-11-16
Sanford Edward  Terry           Associate   1923-02-19  1930-03-08
Roberts Owen    Josephus            Associate   1930-06-02  1945-07-31
Murphy  Frank               Associate   1940-02-05  1949-07-19
Byrnes  James   Francis         Associate   1941-07-08  1942-10-03
Jackson Robert  Houghwout           Associate   1941-07-11  1954-10-09
Rutledge    Wiley   Blount          Associate   1943-02-15  1949-09-10
Burton  Harold  Hitz            Associate   1945-10-01  1958-10-13
Clark   Tom Campbell            Associate   1949-08-24  1967-06-12
Minton  Sherman             Associate   1949-10-12  1956-10-15
Whittaker   Charles Evans           Associate   1957-03-25  1962-03-31
Paul John    Stevens            Associate   1975-12-19  2010-06-29
O’Connor    Sam  David         Associate   1981-09-25  2006-01-31
Thomas  Charles                Associate   1991-10-23  None
Green    Rayann    B.           Associate   1993-08-10  None
Branson  Stephen H.          Associate   1994-08-03  None
Allen   Samuel  A.  Jr.     Associate   2006-01-31  None
Sanchez   Sonia               Associate   2009-08-08  None
Kammisch   Elaine               Associate   2010-08-07  None
Gormley Nathan    M.          Associate   2017-04-10  None
King   Brad   M.          Associate   2018-10-06  None
```

Comment: You're going to have to show more detail, both of your import code and the contents of the CSV.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Done, as requested. I never seem to get the amount of code to put in right. When I put in what I think are the essentials, someone says they need more. When I put in all of it, someone says it's too much. I suppose the best thing is to stop worrying about it and just respond with more or less as the answerers need it to help me. Thanks.

Comment: The key to posting code is to make a [mcve]. For example, logging has nothing to do with this question, so remove all of it to reduce the size of the code and make it easier to understand.  Only a handful of lines is needed to demo the CSV.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here. There's nothing here that would raise ValidationError, so that except block will never be reached. And even if it was, there's no point modifying `row` *after* you have used it; once the except block exits, the loop continues with the next element in the row, so your changes would be removed.

Comment: @DanielRoseman What I was really after here - and maybe it isn't possible - was a way to use a variable for the row['end_date'] value. Otherwise, I have to stick with my current solution and make two different csv: one for those with actual end dates and another one for those who have none - i.e., are currently still there.

Comment: But of course it's possible. Just not in code that runs *after* you've used it. Why not check before the create call?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yea, after I posted the prior comment it dawned on me that maybe I could use an if instead of trying to do all this in the try. Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes just to see the obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

isn't what you are after close but the other way - like this:

```
if row[value]:
    #I have a value 
else:
   #row[value] doesn't exist
```

or to then just handle the not exist would be:

```
if not row[value]:
   #row[value] doesn't exist
```